# Evaluate a date format from a String value

Tags: sql, mysql, databricks, date-arithmetic

I have a requirement where a filed value is "CAH132242F0A" from this i have to come up with a date.
so here "13" is the year and so yyyy = "2013" and "224" th day. so i have to extract this and make it a date format "yyyy-mm-dd".

Can someone help me how to do it?

Comment: What is the earliest year which your string might contain?  Are there any years earlier than 2000?

Comment: Is the format always the same? Three characters that we ignore, two digits for the year, three digits for the day, then some more characters that we ignore? And the year is to be interpreted as the closest until now, i.e. 24 = 1924, 23 = 2023?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen year is always post "2000".

Comment: And pre year 2100?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the format is always the same. first 3 characters we ignore, 2 digits for the year , year is always post "2000" then next 3 digits to generate the day and month.

Comment: So there are always 3 digits for the day, ie Jan 1 is `CAH130012F0A`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the databricks docs on [date/time formats](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) this should work:

```
to_date(substring(code, 4, 5), 'yD')
```

We extract the five digits for yyddd and apply the format 'yD' where y stands for a two- or four-digit year and D for a three-digit day number. The docs say that the base year is always 2000, which is just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_add` twice: once for the year, and again for the day:

```
date_add(date_add('1999-12-31', interval substr(f, 4, 2) year), interval substr(f, 6, 3) day)
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P-VsTxff).

Answer (score 0):

You could use some string manipulation olympics here:

```
SELECT col,
       TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,
                    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 6, 3) AS UNSIGNED) - 1,
                    CAST(CONCAT(2000 + CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 4, 2) AS UNSIGNED), '-01-01') AS date)
       ) AS date
FROM yourTable;  -- 2013-08-13
```

### Demo

Here we use `TIMESTAMPADD` and brute force substring operations to add the correct number of days to January 1 in the year specified.

Comment: It is giving next day . with the above example it should give "12". so if i change the last expr to "-12-31" then it is perfect. 
But just curious when i tried this in my case the output is coming as timestamp format with only 0's added. for example "CAH132963265" got converted into "2014-10-23 00:00:00.000" . i know from here i can typecast it to date with required format like "yyyy-mm-dd" but was curious to know why it is coming as timestamp.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the correct N - 1 number of days.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
    DATE_TRUNC('year', '2000-01-01'::date) + 
    CAST(SUBSTRING('CAH132242F0A' FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) * INTERVAL '1 year' + 
    (CAST(SUBSTRING('CAH132242F0A' FROM 6 FOR 3) AS INTEGER) - 1) * INTERVAL '1 day', 
    'yyyy-mm-dd'
  ) AS date_str;
```

The date is 2013-08-12 (and not 13 !)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table mytable(datecolumn varchar(20));
insert into  mytable values('CAH132242F0A');
```

Query:

```
select makedate( concat('20' ,substring(datecolumn,4,2)),substring(datecolumn,6,Length(datecolumn)-(position('F' in datecolumn))+1)) date
from mytable
```

| date |
| --- |
| 2013-08-12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_sPhw9Vm)